# Heroku custom domains on Cloudflare: Too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cloudflare

**Objectives**

- Run https://rapid.essbap.org through Cloudflare.
- This should map to https://ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com (Rails app)
- However, I get "too many redirects" pages, e.g.

[image]

- Have done this successfully before on other Heroku apps, using steps below
- What am I missing?

**What I did**

- Purchased `essbap.org` through Godaddy.
- Imported DNS to Cloudflare.
- Inserted Cloudflare name servers at Godaddy.
- Removed zone records from Godaddy.

Cloudflare:

- Inserted CNAME record `rapid` to point to `ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com`
- On Heroku: added custom domain `rapid.essbap.org` to `ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com`

Heroku:

```
heroku domains:add rapid.essbap.org

=== ebcc-rrn Heroku Domain
ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com

=== ebcc-rrn Custom Domains
Domain Name       DNS Target
----------------  ----------------------
rapid.essbap.org  ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com 

$ host rapid.essbap.org 
rapid.essbap.org has address 104.27.162.137 
rapid.essbap.org has address 104.27.163.137
```

Cloudflare settings

[image]

**JUST ADDED:**

**Running curl**

When I run `curl` against another Heroku custom domain app that I know works, it looks like:

```
$ curl -I some.custom_app.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://some.custom_app.com/

# since I'm using force_ssl on Rails, we expect to be directed to https://

$ curl -I https://some.custom_app.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Similar behaviour for `ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com` (the Herokuapp we want `rapid.essbap.org` to be an alias for). A 301 then 200.

But when I run `curl` against `rapid.essbap.org`, I get:

```
$ curl -I rapid.essbap.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rapid.essbap.org/

# since I'm using force_ssl on Rails, we expect to be directed to https://

$ curl -I https://rapid.essbap.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rapid.essbap.org/
```

We get a 301 instead of a 200 in the second case. Am not sure why the 301 is being generated. Does not happen in dev or with `ebcc-rrn.herokuapp.com`.

What am I missing?

Comment: also see this solution i posted here, could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141495/deploying-phoenix-application-to-heroku-with-ssl-and-cloudflare-too-many-redire/44093532#44093532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no conclusive solution (but big thanks to Heroku for technical help).

Managed to resolve issue by rolling back and trying again:

- Transferring DNS back to Godaddy
- Wiping domain from Cloudflare
- Ensuring functionality with Godaddy
- Create domain on Cloudflare
- Transfer to Cloudflare again

Now all working as planned.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with my md2pdf.herokuapp.com. Domain is from nic.io and DNS was provided by dyn.com before attempting to switch to cloudflare.

Answer (score 27):

Im my case setting *Crypto -> SSL* `Flexible` to `Full` did the trick.

Comment: Seems this option is now under `SSL/TLS -> Overview`

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue on a site recently, also using Heroku and Cloudflare and SSL.

In our case, the solution was that we had to set the SSL option in Cloudflare under Crypto > SSL to `Flexible`. We had it on `Full`, which was causing the site to try to use CloudFlare's SSL certificate. It didn't work with the SSL option set to `Off`.

Comment: It was the opposite for me - I had SSL setup on my Heroku site, and kept getting the too many redirects with Cloudlfare SSL as `Off` or `Flexible`.  Setting it to `Full (strict)` worked for me as that SSL was already present on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Using Crypto -> "Always use HTTPS": ON directly on CloudFlare did the trick.

SSL is not enforced by rails but by this option.

Not sure if there are any drawbacks with this approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I curl that url over https://rapid.essbap.org/, it looks like you have it redirecting back to https://rapid.essbap.org/

curl -v https://rapid.essbap.org 
* Rebuilt URL to: https://rapid.essbap.org/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:a389...
* Connected to rapid.essbap.org (2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:a389) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: sni95196.cloudflaressl.com
* Server certificate: COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
* Server certificate: COMODO ECC Certification Authority
* Server certificate: AddTrust External CA Root

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
>   Host: rapid.essbap.org
>   Accept: */*
>
> < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   * Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
>   < Server: cloudflare-nginx
>   < Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 23:37:57 GMT
>   < Content-Type: text/html
>   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   < Connection: keep-alive
>   < Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddc8d6151d53a0e3d3eab0789f0b811851438299465; expires=Fri, 29-Jul-16 23:37:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.essbap.org; HttpOnly
>   < Location: https://rapid.essbap.org/
>   < Via: 1.1 vegur
>   < CF-RAY: 20e4e4ab2489281c-SJC

http://rapid.essbap.org/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:a389...
* Connected to rapid.essbap.org (::1) port 80 (#0)

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
>   Host: rapid.essbap.org
>   Accept: */*
>
> < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   < Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 23:40:57 GMT
>   < Content-Type: text/html
>   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   < Connection: keep-alive
>   < Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d5b6d3a1c46df56fcd623454bba7c9d121438299657; expires=Fri, 29-Jul-16 23:40:57 GMT; path=/; domain=.essbap.org; HttpOnly
>   < Location: https://rapid.essbap.org/
>   < Via: 1.1 vegur
>   * Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
>   < Server: cloudflare-nginx
>   < CF-RAY: 20e4e95a0abf281c-SJC

Comment: Thanks, the redirect back is consistent with expected behaviour with Heroku custom domain app. I compared this with working Heroku custom domain apps (as per addition to my question). But ``https://rapid.essbap.org`` should be returning 200 rather than 301. Trying to track down why this is the case.

Comment: If you have access to Cloudflare support requests, it is #508914