# Deploying Phoenix Application to Heroku with SSL and CloudFlare "too many redirects"

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, phoenix-framework, cloudflare

Just recently deployed an Phoenix Application that runs just fine on the localhost.

The domain name is *something*.ai and I would like to make anyone trying to use the **www** version to be redirected to the **non-www** version.

All the DNS is being managed on CloudFlare's free plan.

Worth noting that I'm using https and SSL, everything has been properly configured on Heroku.

For some weird reason I keep getting a "too many redirects" error, although everything seems to be properly set.

Answer (score 2):

I was having exactly the same problem. Follow these steps:

1. under "Page Rules", remove or disable any forwarding rules you might
   have
2. if you're using SSL on Heroku, make sure that your cloudflare dns settings are using .herokudns.com
3. in cloudflare under "DNS", under the "status" column, make sure your **clouds are gray and not orange**. (you want to only use the
   cloudflare DNS, not DNS + proxy